# MySQLi strange errors

Tags: php, class, oop, mysqli, extends

I am trying to extend the MySQLi class.

```
<?php

class DataManager extends mysqli {

    private $username = "me";
    private $password = "notgonnatellyou";
    private $dbname = "data";
    private $host = "sql.my";

    public function __construct() {
        return connect();
    }

    private function connect() {
        $connection = parent::__construct($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
        return $connection;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        autocommit(false);
        if (!($do = parent::query($query))) {
            rollback();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            commit();
            return $do;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Now I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Access level to DataManager::connect() must be public (as in class mysqli) in /me/datamanager.php on line 37

I don't see why it should be public... And if I make it public, it says

> Call to undefined function connect()

But as you see, I just made that function...

Comment: after public it will be call as `$this->connect();` or `self::connect()`

Comment: Show code in which you use your class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is that you can't increase the privacy of methods you inherit from a base class. If you have an instance of `mysqli` and want to call `connect` on it, you would be surprised if it were unexpectedly private. It would be like having a class with an abstract method that wasn't implemented in a child class.

The second problem as @devpro pointed out in their comment is you have to call `connect` as `$this->connect();` rather than just `connect()`.

You will probably discover that a constructor cannot return a value. The "return value" of a constructor is always the instantiated type.

Also, your references to your fields are wrong too. You need to use `$this->host`, `$this->username`, etc.

Comment: Now it says access denied, using password: NO.

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock Because you aren't constructing a connection with a password due to the third problem mentioned in my answer.

Comment: My constructor now contains: "$this->connect();"

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock Indeed, but you can't return something from a constructor. You are essentially just doing `new mysqli();`.

Comment: I'm not returning anything now in my constructor. I'm only having `$this->connect();` now

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock Your references to your fields are also incorrect. I've appended my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Now it's fixed! I used to program in Java, so I didn't have to use $this->. Thank you for your answer.